# Cordova - Control several sounds on Android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, audio, media

I manage to play several sounds on Android (Cordova 4.1) but now I would like to dynamically change the volume of each video.

My code for playing sounds is the following:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
  document.querySelector("#play").addEventListener("touchend", playMP3(), false);

  function playMP3() {
        var mp3_1 = getMediaURL("audio/sound1.mp3");
        var mp3_2 = getMediaURL("audio/sound2.mp3");
        media1 = new Media(mp3_1, null, mediaError);
        media2 = new Media(mp3_2, null, mediaError);
        media1.play();
        media2.play();
  }

  function getMediaURL(s) {
      if(device.platform.toLowerCase() === "android") return "/android_asset/www/" + s;
      return s;
   }
  function mediaError(e) {
      alert('Media Error');
      alert(JSON.stringify(e));
  }
}
```

Then I would like to control volume with something like `media1.volume = 0.5;` from outside the `onDeviceReady` function but I can't make it work...

Any idea of what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the whole package to play and control sounds with Cordova 4.1 and Android 4.4 wich worked for me. To set the volume call the function with something like `onclick=setVolume(media1, "0.5")`
Hope it can help !

```
var media1 = null;
var media2 = null;

//set volume of one sound
function setVolume(media, volume) {
    if (media) {
        media.setVolume(volume);
    }
}

//play the 2 sounds at the same time
function playMP3() {
    var mp3_1 = getMediaURL("audio/media1.mp3");
    var mp3_2 = getMediaURL("audio/media2.mp3");
    media1 = new Media(mp3gauche, null, mediaError);
    media2 = new Media(mp3droite, null, mediaError);
    media1.play();
    media2.play();
}

//for android devices (need the Device Cordova plugin)
function getMediaURL(s) {
    if(device.platform.toLowerCase() === "android") return "/android_asset/www/" + s;
    return s;
}
//help to get log when errors occur
function mediaError(e) {
    alert('Media Error');
    alert(JSON.stringify(e));
}

//launch the 2 sounds when the device is ready
function onDeviceReady() {
    document.querySelector("#playMp3").addEventListener("touchend", playMP3(), false);

}
```